# Makefile: LKM sources as variables not working

Tags: makefile, kernel-module

I tried to compile a loadable kernel module, when I stumbled across this weird problem:

```
obj-m           := $(ROOTKIT).o

# $(ROOTKIT)-y  += $(CORE_OBJS) $(SRCS_OBJS) $(LIBS_OBJS) $(INCL_OBJS)

$(ROOTKIT)-y    += src/core.o src/libs/syscalltable.o src/network_keylog.o src/server.o 
$(ROOTKIT)-y    += src/module_hiding.o src/getdents_hook.o src/socket_hiding.o src/packet_hiding.o 
$(ROOTKIT)-y    += src/port_knocking.o src/privilege_escalation.o src/include/utils.o
ccflags-y       := -I$(SRCS_H) -I$(LIBS_H) -I$(INCL_H)
```

This code works fine as is. But when I use the single line `$(ROOTKIT)-y` which is commented above instead of the three-liner, it only compiles the `$(CORE_OBJS)` which is only one file. I get the output that all functions defined in the other files are undefined.

Why is that so, even though `echo` says the content of these variables are the exact same as writing out every filename? Is there a way listing the object files in variables or do i have to manually type all of them every time I add files in the future?

Output of the `$(XXXX_OBJS)` variables:

```
src/core.o
src/network_keylog.o src/packet_hiding.o src/module_hiding.o src/getdents_hook.o src/port_knocking.o src/server.o src/socket_hiding.o src/privilege_escalation.o
src/libs/syscalltable.o
src/include/utils.o
```

**EDIT**: To have a look at the complete Makefile:

```
# Module name
ROOTKIT     := rootkit

# Build
UNAME       := $(shell uname -r)
MODULEDIR   := /lib/modules/$(UNAME)
BUILDDIR    := $(MODULEDIR)/build
KERNELDIR   := $(MODULEDIR)/kernel

# Source files
SRCS_S      := src
LIBS_S      := src/libs
INCL_S      := src/include

# Header files
SRCS_H      := $(PWD)/$(SRCS_S)/headers
LIBS_H      := $(PWD)/$(LIBS_S)/headers
INCL_H      := $(PWD)/$(INCL_S)/headers

# Initial file
CORE        := src/core.c

# Objects
CORE        := src/core.c
CORE_OBJS   := $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(CORE))
SRCS_OBJS   := $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(filter-out $(CORE), $(wildcard $(SRCS_S)/*.c)))
LIBS_OBJS   := $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(wildcard $(LIBS_S)/*.c))
INCL_OBJS   := $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(wildcard $(INCL_S)/*.c))

# Module
obj-m       := $(ROOTKIT).o

# $(ROOTKIT)-y += $(CORE_OBJS) $(SRCS_OBJS) $(LIBS_OBJS) $(INCL_OBJS)

$(ROOTKIT)-y   += src/core.o src/libs/syscalltable.o src/network_keylog.o src/server.o 
$(ROOTKIT)-y   += src/module_hiding.o src/getdents_hook.o src/socket_hiding.o src/packet_hiding.o 
$(ROOTKIT)-y   += src/port_knocking.o src/privilege_escalation.o src/include/utils.o
ccflags-y   := -I$(SRCS_H) -I$(LIBS_H) -I$(INCL_H)

# Recipes
all:
    $(MAKE) -C $(BUILDDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

load:
    insmod $(KERNELDIR)/net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_reject_ipv4.ko
    insmod $(KERNELDIR)/net/ipv6/netfilter/nf_reject_ipv6.ko
    insmod rootkit.ko

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(BUILDDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: You can use [$(info $(variable) plus some text plus $(another-variable))](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Make-Control-Functions) to write out variable contents at the time of processing which is different (with possibly different variable contents) from the rule-execution phase.

Comment: @Vroomfondel $(info ...) with all variables returns the same as manually writing all variables to `$(ROOTKIT)-y`. But how does this help me? I still can't pass all variables to `$(ROOTKIT)-y` for the compiling of the module.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Can you reduce it to a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Beta A minimal example is complicated in my situation, since the structure is rather "complex". I edited the question and inserted the complete Makefile as it is now, if you want to test ist you will have to clone the repository from github [here](https://github.com/croemheld/lkm-rootkit).

Comment: Have you tried to print content of `rootkit-y` variable? If it contains all your object files, but only one is compiled actually, this could be a [variable's flawor](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_6.html#SEC59) issue: Variable `rootkit-y` is defined as *recursively-expanded*, and is likely dereferenced outside of your makefile, when current directore may differ. However, I am not sure about this.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I tried printing it using `echo` and `$(info $(rootkit-y))` and it prints all files I manually typed in. So it should work, but it doesn't. I cannot believe this would be a flavor issue, since I only used the `:=` operator to assign variables. Since `:=` assigns a value to a variable *at the time the value is assigned without any references to other variables* it should just like a manually typed list of files.

Comment: Yes, the same considerations came to me about flavors. But I have no other explanations for that. For completeness: have you tried  to assign `*_OBJS` variables with hardcoded values instead of `wildcard`? If this works ... then flavors are definitely involved into the problem. `Is there a way listing the object files in variables or do i have to manually type all of them every time I add files in the future?` - In Makefiles for kernel sources all files are listed **explicitly**; the same approach I have used in my projects.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I tried to assign all values to their respective `*_OBJS` variable and it works. *In Makefiles for kernel sources all files are listed explicitly; the same approach I have used in my projects.* - Okay, if they are listed manually then maybe I should consider doing it the same way I guess. I'm just really confused why the way I followed is not working even though the variables have the correct values and all. I think I will be using your approach and leave this question to whoever might be able to explain the real reason. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be misusing [substitution references](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Substitution-Refs).

```
SRCS := foo.c
OBJS_1 := $(SRCS:.c=.o)    # evaluates to 'foo.o'
OBJS_2 := $($(SRCS):.c=.o) # evaluates to nothing
```

The assignment to `OBJS_1` is how substitution refs work; the assignment to `OBJS_2` is simply a syntax error, it expands to `$(foo.c:.c=.o)` and then to '' (since there's no variable with that name). So your assignments like this one:

```
LIBS_OBJS   := $($(wildcard $(LIBS_S)/*.c):.c=.o)
```

result in **empty variables.** I don't know how you got the "Output of the $(XXXX_OBJS) variables" (since nothing in your makefile actually displays them), but in fact only `CORE_OBJS` contains anything, and that's all that gets into `$(ROOTKIT)-y`.

To fix it, just forgo the substitution references and use [patsubst](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions):

```
LIBS_OBJS   := $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(wildcard $(LIBS_S)/*.c))
```

**EDIT:** all right, let's start small and build up.

**Step 1:** Try the following makefile, and tell us the result (in a comment):

```
SRCS_S      := src
SRCS_OBJS   := $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(wildcard $(SRCS_S)/*.c))

SRC_LIST += $(SRCS_OBJS)
$(info $(SRC_LIST))
```

(If the output is unmanageable, you might try it with a source directory containing `foo.c` and `bar.c`)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unformtunately it still does not work. This only compiles the `src/core.c` file and nothing else. Regarding your question how I got the output of the *_OBJS variables: I printed them via @echo or $(info ...). Both of these printed the same result, namely all files I usually typed in manually.